# "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to PLayer" what this meaning?

Tags: java

I am currently working on java project and I am kinda stuck now and having problem.
I am java beginner and not understanding much.
I have problem with thePlayer. It is saying "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to PLayer"
Not sure what is wrong with my code. PLayer is class that I am having to pass values.
I hope get advices from expert. Thank you very much!

```
    private void AddJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    final int MAX_NUMBER = 1000;
    final double BET_COST = 100;
    final double EXACT_MATCH = 10000;
    final double THREE_DIGITS_MATCH = 3000;
    final double TWO_DIGITS_MATCH = 2000;
    final double ONE_DIGIT_MATCH = 1000;

         {output.delete(0,output.length());
        String selectedPlayerName = jList2.getSelectedValue();
         PLayer thePlayer;
         thePlayer = searchmusic(selectedPlayerName);

        if(numberAsString.length() > 0 && !numberAsString.equals("")&&
                numberAsString != null && thePlayer != null &&
                thePlayer.getBalance() >= BET_COST)
```

Comment: Add the code for searchmusic

Comment: Don't try to tell us what the error message says; *actually show the error message*.

Comment: Please provide code, which is throwing the error.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thank you and sorry that I made all of u confused.

Answer (score 0):

You declared thePlayer to be of type Player:

```
Player thePlayer;
```

But you assign it the return of a function called searchmusic. You didn't show the searchmusic function but quite likely, it is defined like:

```
void searchmusic(String selectedPlaydName) {
  // The code of the function
}
```

That function shall return a Player, not void. void means that the function return nothing.